# Hide div when hovering another div

Tags: javascript, css, html, hover, hidden

so i have a few divs inside divs like this:

```
  <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <a href="#" data-reveal-id="pc1">
                <div class="inner" style="background-color:#ea6524;">
                    <p class="text">title</p>
                    <img src="1.png" class="img" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
```

DESCRIPTION:
now the flip-container and the flipper are used because when i hover this div i have a css transition triggered which flips the div. 
the href simply allows to open a div with a description when the inner div is clicked
the inner div is a square with inside a text and an image.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:
i would like to hide the text "title" and the img "1.png" when i hover the flip-container.

how can i do this?

i tried to add display:hidden to the class text but it works only when i hover the actual text and not when i hover the flip-container background.

thanks for the help

i would prefer a pure css solution if possible, if not also a javascript solution could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP,

In this case, I'd suggest `visibility:hidden` over `display:none;`. Here's a fiddle with this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/wEr3T/1/.

In short, `visibility:hidden` will literally **just** hide the element(s)—still taking up the space it did before, thus not affecting the layout.

In contrast, `display:none;` causes it not to be rendered, thus the space it had previously occupied is now unaccounted for. As such, hovering to show/hide elements that have been set to `display:none` will likely cause some undesired flickering.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
.flip-container:hover .text, .flip-container:hover img {
    display: none;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `visibility: hidden` as this will keep the elements in the document flow, rather than removing them all together.

Answer (score 0):

hiding the text and the image when hovering `#flip-container` by setting `display: none` may cause flashing and change in layout of the parent container. so instead make them transparent by set `visibility: hidden`.

```
.flip-container:hover img {
visibility:hidden
}
.flip-container:hover .text {
visibility:hidden
}
```

i have created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akrambe/ASxV5/) for you.

Comment: also visibility hidden works perfectly.. actually resolves issues caused by display none where contents move of position

Answer (score 0):

> Try this...

```css
.flip-container:hover .text, .flip-container:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <a href="#" data-reveal-id="pc1">
                <div class="inner" style="background-color:yellow;">
                    <p class="text" style="color:red">title</p>
                    <img src="//placehold.it/100x100" class="img" />
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
```